# How to save a file with C++ in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file, c++

I did a program in C++ but it does not allow to save on c:\SomeDirectory\afile.txt

I'm using this:

```
FILE* m_hFile = fopen("c:\\SomeDirectory\\afile.txt", "a+t");

fprintf((FILE *)m_hFile, "testing");

fclose(m_hFile);
```

Why that? Is there a defined folder I can save in?

Comment: @GMan: C is a valid subset of C++ ... so, how do you distinguish the 2? How do you know that this snippet is not part of a member function? And has your hair-splitting anything to do with the actual problem?

Comment: You don't need the cast on the second line. `m_hFile` already has the right type.

Comment: @akira: C is not a subset of C++. They're compatible. I didn't say it didn't compile, I said it wasn't C++. What we mean by that is, if this were real C++ code, I'd probably ask them where they learned idiomatic C++. Because, in C++, this code is terrible. You use streams, RAII/SBRM, and never explicitly close things. It's not exception-safe, and it's not type-safe. So I repeat: That's not C++. It's C. (Or terrible C++.) Your pick.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 doesn't allow the creation of files in (subdirectories of?)  the root directory. Maybe try running as admin.

Also, that's very C code, not C++. Use streams/good C++, not C with classes.

Comment: FYI: It does allow you create directories even as a normal user, not files though.

Comment: @tyranid is right, but it still remains a good idea for @okami to run a test as admin (elevated, consenting to a UAC prompt) to rule out such issues.

Answer (score 1):

i assume the `fopen()` yields a valid m_hFile and the rest of the code does not crash either. since your program seems to not be run with admin-permissions that file will be 'redirected' to the 'virtual store'. search for the file in

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\SomeDirectory\afile.txt
```

essentially programs should only write to user-writable areas. read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905330.aspx).

Comment: That's certainly not true for all values of "SomeDirectory". If @okami has given us the real code, virtualization will not apply. Basically the root of C and Program Files are the virtualized ones.